# Closed form solution equations involving finite sums

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I am a beginner in *Mathematica*, so take this into account. I could not find anything similar in the internet so far.

I am trying to find a closed form solution for `A` in the equation below as a function of `n`, where `n` is countable and grows large. Potentially is infinite, but it would suffice to see a result for this when `n` is only large enough. I am using `Reduce` in the following way:

```
Reduce[
  Sum[Subscript[λ, t]*((A + B)/2 + Subscript[b, t] - D - E)^2, {t, 1, n}] == 
    Sum[Subscript[λ, t]*((B + C)/2 + Subscript[b, t] - D - E)^2, {t, 1, n}] && 
  Sum[Subscript[λ, t], {t, 1, n}] == 1,
  A]
```

Apparently `Reduce` is incapable of solving it. Perhaps I need another function.

When I use this specification above and assign numbers for `n`, for instance 3, the result is perfect and delivers what I need. Here is the example:

```
Reduce[Sum[
  Subscript[λ, t]*((A + B)/2 + Subscript[b, t] - D - E)^2, {t, 1, 3}] == 
    Sum[Subscript[λ, t]*((B + C)/2 + Subscript[b, t] - D - E)^2, {t, 1, 3}] && 
  Sum[Subscript[λ, t], {t, 1, 3}] == 1, 
  A]
```

Here is the output -- it is in the closed form solution that I am looking for:

```
A == 
  -2 B - C + 4 D + 4 E - 4 Subscript[b, 1] + 
  4 Subscript[b, 1] Subscript[λ, 2] - 
  4 Subscript[b, 2] Subscript[λ, 2] + 
  4 Subscript[b, 1] Subscript[λ, 3] - 
  4 Subscript[b, 3] Subscript[λ, 3]
```

Could you try to help me out with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sum _{t=1}^n l(t) \left(\frac{\text{A}+\text{B}}{2}+b(t)-\text{D}-\text{E}\right)^2-\sum _{t=1}^n l(t)
   \left(b(t)+\frac{\text{B}+\text{C}}{2}-\text{D}-\text{E}\right)^2=0$

$\sum _{t=1}^n (\text{A}-\text{C}) l(t) (\text{A}+4 b(t)+2 \text{B}+\text{C}-4 \text{D}-4 \text{E})=0$

Then

$\text{A}=\text{C}$

Or since $\sum _{t=1}^n l(t)=1$

$\text{A}=-4 b.l-2 \text{B}-\text{C}+4 \text{D}+4 \text{E}$

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly that form.

Answer (score 6):

I have rewritten your equations as

```
Sum[λ[t]*((a + b)/2 + β[t] - d - e)^2, {t, 1, n}] == 
  Sum[λ[t]*((b + c)/2 + β[t] - d - e)^2, {t, 1, n}] && 
Sum[λ[t], {t, 1, n}] == 1
```

because identifiers `C`, `D`, and `E` are reserved for system use in *Mathematica* and because subscripts are a pain in computation.

I can't find a closed form solution for `a`, but by doing a little math I could derive a recursive definition.

```
a[1] = -2 b - c + 4 d + 4 e - 4 β[1];
a[n_Integer /; n > 1] := (a[n] = a[n - 1] + 4 β[1] λ[n] - 4 β[n] λ[n])
```

This, for example, gives

```
a[7]
```

> ```
> -2 b - c + 4 d + 4 e - 4 β[1] + 
> 4 β[1] λ[2] - 4 β[2] λ[2] + 4 β[1] λ[3] - 4 β[3] λ[3] + 
> 4 β[1] λ[4] - 4 β[4] λ[4] + 4 β[1] λ[5] - 4 β[5] λ[5] + 
> 4 β[1] λ[6] - 4 β[6] λ[6] + 4 β[1] λ[7] - 4 β[7] λ[7]
> ```

A little further analysis, using the relation `Sum[λ[t], {t, 1, n}] == 1`, gives

```
a[n_Integer?Positive] := 1 - 2 b - c + 4(d + e - Sum[β[t] λ[t], {t, 1, n}])
```

That is a far as I can carry the analysis, not knowing any details of `β[t]` and `λ[t]`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Impressively helpful.